# How do you correctly mix textx skipws/non-skipws?

Tags: python, textx

I want to use textx to parse `"foo bar."` differently to `"foo bar ."` (tying the `'.'` to the last word if there's no space, but still parsing the `'.'` separately).

I would have thought the following would do this:

```
from textx.metamodel import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
Sentence[skipws]: words*=Word;
Word[noskipws]: ID '.' | ID | '.';
''')
```

But it parses the following as two instead of three 'words':

```
>>> print(len(mm.model_from_str('''foo bar .''').words))
2
```

It appears to work as I expect if I instead do:

```
from textx.metamodel import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
Sentence[skipws]: (words=Word /(?i) */)*;
Word[noskipws]: ID '.' | ID | '.';
''', skipws=False)
```

It's unclear to me why the skipws=False is necessary here, or the manual regex... and if I leave off the `(?i)` it throws an exception ('nothing to repeat').

Answer (score 1):

`skipws/noskipws` [applies immediately](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#rule-modifiers) thus the first match of your `Word` rule will see the preceding spaces before `ID` so `ID '.'` will never match. You must consume those spaces. Here is how it is done:

```py
mm = metamodel_from_str('''
Sentence[skipws]: words*=Word;
Word[noskipws]: /\s*/- (ID '.' | ID | '.');
''')

print(mm.model_from_str('foo bar.', debug=True).words)
```

The `-` operator after `/\s*/` is [match suppression](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#match-suppression), meaning that we don't want that part of the match to end up in our `Word`. It is always good to run parsing with `debug=True` to see what is happening behind the scenes.

**Update 2019-10-02:** There was a bug in `OrderedChoice` that introduced confusion to the way `skipws` worked in the context of alternative choices. It was fixed in Arpeggio parser as of version 1.9.1.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an accurate description of what's happening. The problem is that ID '.' is matching when it shouldn't, not that it would never match. The suggested change does fix what's happening, but I don't properly understand the mechanism.

It also doesn't explain why it behaves differently with the global modifier (skipws=False) than without, even with the same individual modifiers.

Also - why does `/ */` not work?

Comment: (note that I'm using /(?i) */ still, because I can't use \s since it includes \n)

Comment: To clarify further, this is a subset of a more complex grammar that I can't get to behave appropriately. I've also used debug mode and it's not clear to me why it's eating the spaces when noskipws is there. If I make either my 'fix' or your 'fix', it doesn't fix the behaviour in the more complex grammar.

Comment: @james.haggerty I think you are right. Something wrong is going on here. Although the solution above is how it should be done, the way your original example is behaving looks buggy. It seems that `skipws` is canceling `noskipws` in `Word`. Could you please register this in issue tracker so we could investigate further?

Comment: BTW, you can change per rule what is considered to be a whitespace by `ws` rule modifier http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#rule-modifiers

Comment: On further thought, I'm wondering if the odd skipws behaviour is to do with the use of 'ID' (i.e. that with skipws=True, the ID has skipws=True and can therefore sometimes swallow spaces). Doesn't explain everything, however.

Comment: @james.haggerty Added a note on Arpeggio OrdererdChoice bug fix. `ws` rule modifier is propagated to all referred rules the same as `skipws`.